# How to get a particular value from Json using SelectToken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON like this

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "$type": "Dictionary`2",
    "Id": "6448DE37E2F3D9588118A1950"
  },
  "Databases": [
    {
      "$type": "Pime",
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Peter",
      "MobNo": 78877629,
      "PAN": "SAKKJKJ",
      "Defaulter": true,
    },
    {
      "$type": "Pime",
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "James",
      "MobNo": 58277699,
      "PAN": "NAQKJKJ",
      "Defaulter": false,
    },
    {
      "$type": "Pime",
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Norton",
      "MobNo": 38877699,
      "PAN": "TAKKJKJ",
      "Defaulter": true,
    },
  ]
}
```

I'm using a token to select the node and return the customer information whose Id=2

My code goes like this:

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\TestJson\Test.db");
string json = r.ReadToEnd();
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken result = o.SelectToken("$.Databases[?(@.Id == '2')]");
```

But I am getting the result as null. Am I using the wrong token in the SelectToken() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all given JSON is invalid, in `database` array value of `Name` and `PAN` keys should be of type `string`. You are missing `"`(double qoutes) in above json.

Second and most important thing, type of `Id` is an integer and in your Json Path you are trying to search with string type i.e `'2'`, try to search `Id` by integer without quoute it will work.

```
//No single qoutes for 2.
JToken result = o.SelectToken("$.Databases[?(@.Id == 2)]");
```

Comment: I have updated the Name, Pan into string. It was a typo.